# microsoft sql server basic advanced python integration differences

Tags: python, sql-server, database, licensing

Does anyone know what the specific differences are between the various Python integrations options for Microsoft SQL 2017 Servers? The table shows[sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnjKP.png)

But what are the actual differences between 'basic' and 'advanced' integration? Has anyone had any experience with the different types of integration?

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/differences-in-r-features-between-editions-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its about full parallelism for RRE -- not sure it actually applies to Python support. [enter link description here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/A/2/8A2BC8C5-BBA0-4A9C-90BC-AC957D3454D9/SQL_Server_2016_Editions_datasheet.pdf)

FWIW Lots of the docs about Python are incomplete or just plain wrong

Answer (score 0):

From the link you posted: "The difference between basic and advanced integration is scale. Advanced integration can use all available cores for parallel processing of data sets at any size your computer can accommodate. Basic integration is limited to 2 cores and to data sets fitting in memory."

So basic integration is similar using the open-source Python or R runtimes.  Data Frames must fit in memory, and stuff runs single-threaded.  The Advanced integration enables the full functionality of Microsoft Machine Learning Server.

> Microsoft Machine Learning Server includes a rich set of
>   highly-scalable, distributed set of algorithms such as RevoscaleR,
>   revoscalepy, and microsoftML that can work on data sizes larger than
>   the size of physical memory, and run on a wide variety of platforms in
>   a distributed manner

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/what-is-machine-learning-server

Comment: Thanks David,  I think what is missing is a side-by-side feature comparison for advanced vs basic

Comment: From this answer it sounds like you could do anything functionality wise, and it only affects performance? I'm curious if I could still use any library and/or IDLE etc. with basic integration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur if you're still looking for an answer. But Here is what I noticed for myself ans I thought that would help.

1 Basic integration is limited to 2 cores and in-memory data sets.

2 Advanced integration can use all available cores for parallel processing of data sets at any size subject to hardware limits.

It is in the same page as the link you posted, just scroll down.